# jquery width issue in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue getting the div width in IE8 ,it is fine in FF and chrome.
I'm getting the width as 0 in IE , 1366 in FF and chrome.

```
     $('.fs-pic').width();
```

html:

```
    <div class="fs-pic"> <img id="full" src=""/></div>
```

I've put the width as auto for the fs-pic class.

the above line returns 0 in IE. Is there any alternate for IE?
Any help please.

Comment: Which `JQuery` version are you using?

Comment: @Vucko  jquery 1.10.2

Comment: try your code inside ready.....

Comment: There is some issue with `jquery 1.10 ` and IE it show $ is undefined

Comment: maybe because of DOCTYPE declaration..

Comment: I will suggest either upgrade jquery version or downgrade it

Comment: Try it inside $(window).load(function () { });

Answer (score 0):

did you put it in `$(document).ready()`?
try move it in `$(window).load()` i think it's because the image (that is creating the container's width) is not loaded yet..so it returned 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$(window).load(function(){...});` instead of document ready.

If it still not working, then this could work, using a timer let the DOM be fully rendered, play with speed a bit (try 3000 if 1000 doesn't work).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(jQuery('.fs-pic').width());

        jQuery('#accordion-wrapper').raccordion({
            speed: 1000,
            sliderWidth: jQuery('.fs-pic').width(),
            sliderHeight: 360,
            autoCollapse: false
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

I noticed that `outerWidth()` and `innerWidth()` can help but I haven't tried those.

Answer (score 0):

Try code when document is ready, might be dom not loaded and we are calling before dom is loaded.
IE browser take more time compare to FF and Chrome to load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fs-pic').width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [load-event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) to the image. When the image is loaded the event fires:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fs-pic img').load(function() {
         alert($('.fs-pic').width()));
    });
});
```

I have an working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muffls/V79G6/9/), that shows you, that even in Chrome, when you load a large image or have a slow connection or a slow browser, the width of a span wrapping an image can be 0. When you rerun the JSFiddle, the image will be in the browser cache and therefore accessing the width inside `$(document).ready()` will work too.